# how to find the series name using vba?

Tags: vba, excel

I have written vba code for naming the series in a graph:

```
 ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).name = "SPEC"
 ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).name = "manju"
```

My problem is that I want to find the particular series name using vba code.
In the above code I have two series.
Now I want find the series name (manju) by using vba code.

Comment: Is there any reason why `MsgBox(ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).name)` wouldn't work?

Comment: @LynnCrumbling I want to search all series because every time it will b different position

Comment: @LynnCrumbling it may be in series 5 or any where

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To access the `SeriesCollection()` by passing the name you can:

```
MsgBox ActiveChart.SeriesCollection("manju").Name
```

That's possible because `index` in the `SeriesCollection(index)` is actually of `Variant` type so the compiler works out if you are passing a `String` type and trying to access it by name or if you are passing a `Long/Integer` (*or any other numeric data type*) to access the enumerator.

or iterate the SeriesCollection, comparing the current name against "manju":

```
For i = 1 to ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Count
   If ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).name = "manju" Then
      MsgBox "Found it!"
      Exit for
   End if
Next
```

Comment: Lynn, does this mean you can't access the series by name?

Comment: @rrs Correct -- neither the `.Item()` method nor the indexer support a string... just an index number.

Comment: For Office 2007 (I haven't checked on earlier versions), you definitely can access the `SeriesCollection` by it's name.  Ie `ActiveChart.SeriesCollection("manju")`.  See Office 2010 documentation here which states it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836171%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Comment: @CuberChase I took a look at that page, but there's no indication that name is a valid indexer for `SeriesCollection`. Perhaps you were looking the `Worksheets` or `Charts` collection.

Comment: SeriesCollection just holds a collection of, well, Series. The properties of a Series can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840677(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Note that to index `.SeriesCollection` using a string _variable_, you may need to cast the variable, e.g. `.SeriesCollection(CVar(sName))` - this tripped me up for a bit.